# Making a column of STATE

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a data like this -

```
ID     CITY     STATE     Location
1       a         b          a
1       c         w          a
2       e         b          e
2       a         f          e
```

I want a new column of STATE such that when CITY and Location are same then STATE is "b" for all ID's.

**Expected Output:**

```
ID     CITY     STATE     Location     STATE2
1       a         b          a           b
1       c         d          w           b 
2       e         m          e           m
2       u         f          e           m
```

Comment: Your expected output seems a little off. What should be the value of `State2` when `City` and `Location` are not same?

Comment: It should be filled by the value of STATE when CITY and Location are same @MayankPorwal

Comment: And what about when they are not same? What values should it be filled with then?

Comment: assume that id's are same for this example. sorry for not describing it properly

Comment: lets say for id 2, c and a are not same but state should be "b" i.e. when city and location are same

Comment: @MayankPorwal I think question is more clear now.

Comment: Yes, now its clear.

Comment: @MohammadAmir please fix your input data. It is not the same data for the columns excluding STATE2. With that said, please see my answer. Your wording `when CITY and Location are same then STATE is "b" for all ID's.` is extremely confusing. I think you mean `when CITY and Location are same then STATE is the first state of the ID group for all ID's.` If "first state of the ID group for all ID's" is incorrect, then do you want the first state that has the same `City` and `Location` for each ID. Please advise that any detail like this could potentially be a completely different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see two solutions depending on what you are trying to do.

**Solution #1:**
Assuming the input:

```
   ID CITY STATE Location
0   1    a     b        a
1   1    c     d        w
2   2    e     m        e
3   2    u     f        e
```

You can use `mask` to change `STATE` values for `ID` that have at least one matching row of `CITY` and `Location`:

```
m = df.loc[df['CITY'] == df['Location'], 'ID']
df['STATE 2'] = df['STATE'].mask(df['ID'].isin(m),
                                 df.groupby('ID')['STATE'].transform('first'))
df
Out[1]: 
   ID CITY STATE Location STATE 2
0   1    a     b        a       b
1   1    c     d        w       b
2   2    e     m        e       m
3   2    u     f        e       m
```

**Solution #2:**

Assuming slightly different input (the approach changes a good amount depending on desired output):

```
   ID CITY STATE Location
0   1    g     f        c
1   1    a     b        a
2   1    c     d        w
3   2    e     m        e
4   2    u     f        e

m = df.loc[df['CITY'] == df['Location']].drop_duplicates('CITY').index
df['State 2'] = np.where(df.index.isin(m), df['STATE'], np.nan)
df['State 2'] = df.groupby('ID')['State 2'].transform('first')
df
Out[2]: 
   ID CITY STATE Location State 2
0   1    g     f        c       b
1   1    a     b        a       b
2   1    c     d        w       b
3   2    e     m        e       m
4   2    u     f        e       m
```

This solution assumes you want the output to be the first row within each group that matches. Please see my comment. One of these two solutions are hopefully what you are looking for.

Comment: This will fail if the row with `City == Location` is not the first row in every group.

Comment: no, it won't fail. It just defaults to grabbing the first value as the output is not clear. Please see my comment in the question.

Comment: Nice approach!! You don't need `.astype(str)`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.where`:

```
In [1724]: import numpy as np

In [1732]: x = df.loc[df.CITY == df.Location, 'STATE'].unique()[0]

In [1725]: df['STATE2'] = np.where(df.CITY == df.Location, df.STATE, x)

In [1726]: df
Out[1726]: 
   ID CITY STATE Location STATE2
0   1    a     b        a      b
1   2    c     d        a      b
2   3    e     b        a      b
3   4    a     b        a      b
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
df.loc[df["City"]==df["Location"],"state2"] = "b"
```

Solution 2: if you would like to specify a value for rows that do no match

```
df.apply(lambda x: "b" if x["City"]==x["Location"] else "others",axis=1 )
```

Solution 3: if the conditions are more complex then its better to use a mask

```
mask = (df['City']==df["Location"])
df["state3"] = df["state3"].mask(mask,"b")
```